# How to create a RPM which install python dependencies?

Tags: python-2.7, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, centos5

I have a python application that has flask dependency.

All I need is to create an RPM out of this application and with this RPM I should be able to install the dependencies to another machine.

Things I have tried,

1. Created a setup.py file,

```
setup(
    name='sample-package',
    version='1.0.0.0',
    author="Niranj Rajasekaran",
    author_email="nrajasekaran@test.com",
    package_dir={'': 'src/py'},
    namespace_packages=['main'],
    packages=find_packages('src/py/'),
    install_requires=['Flask']
)
```

2. Ran this command

   `python setup.py bdist_rpm`
3. Got two RPMs in `dist/`, one is noarch and other is src
4. I tried to install noarch rpm using this

   `yum install {generated-file}.rpm`

I am able to get `sample-package-1.0.0.0.egg` file in `site-packages` but not flask.

Two questions,

1. Is my approach correct?
2. If so what is something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bdist_rpm` lacks of a lot of functionality and IMO is not very well maintained. E.g. `pyp2rpm` is much better for converting existing PyPI modules. But your module does not seem to be on PyPI, so you need to specify it to `bdist_rpm` manually because it cannot retrieve this information from `setup.py`.

Run:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --requires python-flask
```

This will produce an rpm file which requires the `python-flask` package. For more recent RHEL/Fedora it would be `python3-flask`.